# Prove that the set of reachable values is convex.

Tags: measurable-functions

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ be an integrable function.

Prove that the set $$\left\{\int_A f(x)\ \mathrm dx: A\subset [0,1] \text { is measurable}\right\}$$ is convex.

Proving the statement ends up being equivalent to proving that $$\forall \alpha\in[0,1]: \exists A_\alpha\ \text{s.t } \int_{A_\alpha} f = \alpha \int_0^1 f$$

My first idea was to try and find a set $A_\alpha$ with density $\alpha$ on every subset of $[0,1]$, but that turned out to be impossible for non trivial cases.
So I tried to approach $f$ with piecewise constant functions on $[0,1]$, but I couldn't find a way to tell anything relevant about $f$'s set of reachable values from the sets of the functions that approach it.

Comment: Why is the first statement equivalent to the second one?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed positive? in $L^1$?

Comment: $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ and takes values in $R^n$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. What statement is supposed to be equivalent to that other thing?

Comment: @zhw the one in the title. You get the second statement by using the definition of a convex set on the points $0$ and $\int_0^1 f$ with parameter $\alpha$.

Comment: Is $f\in L^1$? If so, then say so.

Comment: @zhw I'm explicitly integrating the function on arbitrary measurable sets. It's pretty obvious that it's in $L^1$

Comment: The first statement implies the second. I don't see an equivalence. It seems likely that the result is false. We should perhaps look for a counterexample. For example what happens for $f(t) = e^{i \pi t}$? Or a curve with 2 segments?

Comment: @Gribouillis The second statement implies the first one as well. Suppose we've proven the second statement for all functions and parameters. To prove the first one, take two sets $A$ and $B$.  
We need to find a set $C_\alpha$ s.t. $\int_C f = \alpha \int_A f + (1-\alpha)\int_B f$  
We choose $C=(A\cap B) \cup A_\alpha \cup B_{1-\alpha}$
Where $A_\alpha$ and $B_{1-\alpha}$ are such that $\int_{A_\alpha} f = \alpha\int_{A-B} f$ and $\int_{B_{1-\alpha}} f = (1-\alpha)\int_{B-A} f$.  
There are a couple details that need to be taken care of but that's the jist of it.

Comment: A detail is that you need $\int_{A-B}$ instead of $\int_0^1$. I see the idea, but the second statement needs to be improved. You could have written all this in your question. That said, I suggest to start with simple examples such as $f(t) = (t, 1)^\top$ for example.

Comment: @Gribouillis For $f(t) = (t,1)$, $\int_0^1 f = (1/2,1)$. For $\alpha\in[0,1]$, we can choose $A_\alpha = [(1-\alpha)/2,(1+\alpha)/2]$, then $\int_{A_\alpha} f = (\alpha/2 ,\alpha) = \alpha \int_0^1 f$

Comment: It's not what I mean. I'd like to see $\{\int_A f(t) d t, A\subset [0,1]\}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis For a subset of length $\alpha$, the second term is $\alpha$, and the first term can be any number between $\alpha^2/2$ and $\alpha(1-\alpha/2)$. So the set of "reachable" values is $\{(x,y) \text{ s.t. } y^2/2\leq x\leq y(1-y/2)\}$, which is convex since the lower bound is convex and the upper bound is concave.

Comment: https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/intermediate-value-property-of-measures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F\subseteq L^1([0,1])^*$ be the set of a.e. equivalence classes of functions $F:[0,1]\to [0,1],$ equipped with the weak-* topology. $\mathcal F$ is a compact set by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, and it's convex.
The image of $\mathcal F$ under the map $f^*:L^1([0,1])^*\to\mathbb R^n$ defined by $F\mapsto \int fF$ is a compact convex set. This image obviously contains the set defined in the question. We want to show that any point $y\in f^*(\mathcal F)$ can be represented by the indicator function of a set, i.e. $y=f^*(F)$ for some $\{0,1\}$-valued function $F\in\mathcal F.$

By the Krein-Milman theorem, the set $(f^*)^{-1}(y)\cap\mathcal F$ has an extreme point $F.$ I claim that $F$ is the indicator function of a set.

Suppose for contradiction that $\{x\mid 0<F(x)<1\}$ has positive measure. Let $X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}$ be disjoint positive measure subsets of $\{x\mid 0<F(x)<1\},$ using the fact that $[0,1]$ is non-atomic.
Define $D_\lambda(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\lambda_i \min(F(x),1-F(x)) 1_{X_{i}}(x)$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb R^{n+1}.$ Note $f^*(D_\lambda)$ is linear in $\lambda.$ Since $f^*$ has rank at most $n$ there is some $\lambda\in[-1,1]^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f^*(D_\lambda)=0,$ giving $F=\tfrac12((F+D_\lambda)+(F-D_{\lambda})).$ Since $F+D_\lambda$ and $F-D_\lambda$ are both in $(f^*)^{-1}(y)\cap\mathcal F$ and distinct from $F,$ this proves that $F$ is not an extreme point, contradicting the choice of $F.$

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I've been a bit busy lately and haven't found a good chance to carefully read your proof. I've put a new bounty since the previous one ended up running out. I should be able to award it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer for the first version of the question, where we had $f: {\mathbb R}^n\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$

For your second statement, assuming $f\in L^1(E)$, consider for $t\in {\mathbb R}$
$$\phi(t) = \int_E f(x)\chi_{x_1\le t} d\mu$$
then $\phi$ is continuous in ${\mathbb R}$ by the dominated convergence theorem and $\lim_{t\to-\infty}\phi(t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\phi(t) = \int_E f(x) d\mu$, so that $\phi$ reaches any value between $0$ and $\int_E f d\mu$.

**Edit** Still supposing that $f \in L^1(E)$, I realize that the above argument applies to any measurable subset $A\subset E$, so that the whole interval $\left[0, \int_A f d\mu\right]$ belongs to the set $C =\{\int_X f d\mu,X\subset E\}$. It follows that $C$ is a union of intervals that all contain $0$ and therefore it is an interval containing $0$.

With very little more work, one sees that
$$C = \left[-\int_E f^- d\mu, \int_E f^+d\mu\right]$$
where $f^- = \max(0, -f)$ and $f^+ = \max(0,f)$.
QED

Comment: I made a mistake when stating the question. What I need to prove is something different.

Comment: @Fannight Well, start another thread then!

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to answer the second version of the question with $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$.

If $f$ is piecewise constant, i.e.~if $f$ takes only $N$
values ${V}_{1} , \cdots  , {V}_{N}$, let ${m}_{k}$ be the measure
of ${f}^{{-1}} ({V}_{k})$, then obviously for any subset $A$, the
function $f \left(t\right) {{\chi}}_{A} \left(t\right)$ will take the same values, and one has

$$\int_{A}^{}f d t = \sum _{i = 1}^{N} {{\alpha}}_{k} {V}_{k}$$

where ${{\alpha}}_{k} \in  \left[0 , {m}_{k}\right]$. Every such sum is reachable,
so that the reachable set is the convex set
$$C = \left\{\sum _{i = 1}^{N} {{\alpha}}_{k} {V}_{k} , \quad  \forall  k , {{\alpha}}_{k} \in  \left[0 , {m}_{k}\right]\right\}\qquad (1)$$

For non piecewise constant function, one could build an approximation of the
reachable set by the following construction: partition ${\mathbb{R}}^{n}$ in a sequence
of disjoint cubes of side ${\epsilon}$

$${\mathbb{R}}^{n} = \bigcup_{j \in  \mathbb{N}} {K}_{j}^{{\epsilon}}$$

and let ${V}_{j}^{{\epsilon}}$ be the center of the cube ${K}_{j}^{{\epsilon}}$.
We approximate $f$ by a piecewise constant function ${f}_{{\epsilon}}$ by
defining

$${f}_{{\epsilon}} \left(t\right) = {V}_{j}^{\epsilon} \quad  \text{if} \  f \left(t\right) \in  {K}_{j}^{{\epsilon}}$$

Then formula (1) defines a convex set ${C}^{{\epsilon}}$ approximating the set $C$
of reachable values.

This proof is not complete of course, it remains to prove some kind of convergence
result for the obtained family ${C}^{{\epsilon}}$.

Comment: I had a similar approach, but the part I had trouble with is the convergence of the family of sets. I'm not sure if there's a convenient way to say that a family of sets converges. I think it would be easier to do if we had more properties about the set of reachable values. I think it's closed in $R^n$ for all functions but I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: You could start with a regular $f$. For such a function, the approximation by the piecewise constant function is uniform. You could try to prove that if $x \in C$, then $d(x,C_\epsilon)$ tends to 0 for example. You could say that $x$ is in the limit set if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects all the $C^\epsilon$ when $\epsilon$ is small enough, etc. There are many options.